# Setting up a local SVN repository with encrypted passwords with TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, passwords, repository, svn

I am planning on using a local repository, using only TortoiseSVN's "create repository here" feature.

The repo is created and I can read and write to it just fine.  The problem is that I can't get authentication to work.  I thought I wanted Windows authentication, but I actually want the simple text-file based authentication so I can force the current system user (i.e. any person can be using the same Windows account and I want to differentiate between them) to provide their name and password.  I haven't found any information on how to do this without svnserve running.

So far, I have modified `svnserve.conf` like this:

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
realm = LocalOnly
```

I didn't mess with the [sasl] section.

I also modified `passwd`:

```
[users]
harry = teH0wLIpW0gyQ
```

I am trying to use encrypted passwords created with a [simple perl script](http://queens.db.toronto.edu/~nilesh/linux/subversion-howto/).  However, regardless of what I do with the repo (i.e. including writing to the repo), I am never prompted for a password.

I tried clearing TortoiseSVN's authentication cache since I do connect to a remote repo, but this didn't matter at all.

Has anyone tried this and succeeded?  Or is it not possible without svnserve?

Comment: Why do you want to use passwords for a local repository? Why don't just set your NTFS permissions? You ain't putting the local repository on a network share, are you?

Comment: @Albin this is for public use, and I'd like to have a free way of tracking who's putting files where.

Comment: I am have not tried this create repository option in TortoiseSVN, but how will you be able to checkout the repo without a server( I mean svnserve ?). Does tortoise make use of IIS ?

Comment: @VCB you just have to use the file:// syntax.  If your repo is in C:\LocalRepo, then you hit it with file:///c:/localrepo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/). you can edit the file you are mentioning using the GUI provided by the tool. It uses its own http server(not svnserve or IIS).

Comment: this totally did the trick.  I didn't want to have a web server running, and Java takes up 250MB when using Edge, but that's just the way it goes, I guess.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible without svnserve - it takes care of the challenge/response.

Comment: Is there a easy way to install it so that it works with the existing repo?  I looked into something like VisualSVN, which is super easy to install, but it seems to only want to use Windows Authentication.

Comment: @Dave you can just copy your existing repositories to the folders that are needed with either `svnserve` or `VisualSVN Server`

Comment: @Matthew I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow this... there isn't any existing repo to copy.  I'm creating a new one on one computer which doesn't have svnserve on it.  I'm just trying to create a quick and dirty SVN repo without having to deal with much of the administration stuff.

Comment: @Dave, You may copy those local respoitory files to an SVN server and it will just work if you want to upgrade to a server later.  No special import is required.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your best bet with a local repository is to use your file system permissions.  A simple and free option for a server (that's easy to manager) would be [VisualSVN Server](http://visualsvn.com/server/download/).  You can hang it off or a workstation or drop it on a public webserver somewhere.  I now have mine setup with a reverse proxy with IIS7 so it's integrated with the rest of my web site.

Comment: thanks, but from what I've read about VisualSVN is that it wants to use Windows authentication.  I have one Windows user that's always logged in, and I would like a really basic user authentication layer on top of this.  So a Windows user named John Doe logs in, but when he wants to write changes to the repo, he can log in with his "real" account, e.g. Bob.  Bob leaves and Fred walks up and makes changes, and he can commit them using his account "Fred".  This allows me to see who's changing what files.

Comment: VisualSVN can use windows or local/http authentication.